# How do you query your dataset when you zoom into and out of a d3 map?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, dynamic-data, geo

1. How do you add interactivity to d3 maps?
2. I want to add functionality to query my dataset when you zoom into and out of a d3 map. Is there a callback or something that will enable me to do this?
   *2.1 I also want the transition to the new data displayed once you zoom to be fairly seamless.*

Comment: generally you use the same events as you use to make html interactive, clicks, hovers, etc.

Comment: Do you like this example? http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797 I'm pretty sure you can make a custom load function for tiles that are "close" to the viewport in order to query your database.

Answer (score 0):

[d3.behavior.zoom has 3 event handlers](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#on):

> 1.) zoomstart - at the start of a zoom gesture (e.g., touchstart).
>
> 2.) zoom - when the view changes (e.g., touchmove).
>
> 3.) zoomend - at the end of the current zoom gesture (e.g., touchend).

So, it seems to be your case fits the zoomend scenerio:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .on("zoom", zoomed)
  .on("zoomend", zoomend);

function zoomed() {
  features.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function zoomend(){
  // query dataset and do awesome stuff!!
}
```